# Mouse cursor jittery when hover state on browsers in OS X Lion

Tags: mouse, trackpad

I recently upgraded to OS X Lion from Snow Leopard. One bug I've found is that in browsers (Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera), when you hover over any link, the cursor doesn't only change, it jitters around for a second before changing.

Since the bug is annoying but difficult to explain, I tried to make a short clip of it. This is weird: it doesn't show up on video when recorded with various screen recording softwares. How odd.

It's driving me nuts. Does anyone have a fix for this, or have experienced this problem?

I'm using:

- MacBook Pro 2010
- Trackpad
- All web browsers
- Hovering over links
  Quickly

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a mouse to test with? Does that have the same problem?

Comment: I've tried it, same problem with mouse.

Comment: I had a similar problem. With a mouse plugged in the :hover for links when using the trackpad didn't work - they did when using the mouse. Without a mouse plugged in the trackpad performs :hover just fine.

Comment: This is not just in browsers. When typing in Xcode now, the cursor position changes when I try to arrow select from autocomplete menus. VERY frustrating. (Among about 100 other things I'm beginning to loathe about Lion, but must accept, as I need it to run the latest Xcode.)

Comment: By any chance, do you have Parallels Desktop installed? If you do, what versions of Parallels and Lion?

Comment: I have Mountain Lion and I used to have Parallels Desktop 8.0.18354, but I uninstalled it. The issue persists to this day, even with a new laptop. I've always had a feeling it was something I install and use on all my computers that messes with the display driver.

Answer (score 2):

Since this seems to persist, you might need to perform some more troubleshooting to narrow it down:

1. Test by creating an entirely new user account on the Mac with the problem and see if the issue is repeatable.
2. Log when and where the issue happens (assuming it's not a 100% guaranteed item that you can make happen any time you want in 5 seconds of setup).
3. Install a clean OS onto an external USB drive and see if that setup has the issue.
4. File a bug or work with Apple to isolate the issue further.

The clue that the screen recording is clear, but the artifact is visual seems like a great thing to capture with a video recording of the screen and a simultaneous camera recording of the image from the screen. The frequency and placement of the issue might be enough for someone else to diagnose a likely culprit.

Comment: I have a new computer now, and I still notice the jitteryness. I believe it's part of every OS X release past Snow Leopard. I'm just a vigilant computer user with OCD.

Comment: Aah - that might actually make sense - if the cursor hovers on a pixel boundary - it can jump a bit. I was thinking it was a larger motion more than a pixel.